# WebView can’t load the image

Tags: android, html, image, webview

I want to open this url http://shop.m.taobao.com/shop/shopIndex.htm?user_id=61696631 with WebView, however, I found the WebView can’t load any image for this url. If I open this url with browser, it load image normally. Who can help me? Thanks! My code is below and it can’t work.

```
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("myUrl"));//load url

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
 {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably should show us class `MyWebViewClient`.

Comment: I have posted the MyWebViewClient :)